# Is there is some way to unrevoke or re-grant app permissions from Trello?

Tags: trello, permissions, harvest

I was doing some tests on my boards and I revoked permissions of Harvest app and others. Now I can't get it working well again with my Trello account.

Answer (score 1):

You have to https://trello.com/1/authorize?expiration=never&name=SinglePurposeToken&key=REPLACEWITHYOURKEY and generate the token again accepting the "Server token" application.